# “settings.DATABASES is improperly configured” error performing syncdb with django 1.6.8

Tags: python, django, eclipse, devstack

I've setup devstack juno and django version 1.6.8. when want to run this command

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I got this following error:

```
WARNING:root:No local_settings file found.
CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.
```

I configured settings.py of django and this file looks like:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = '{{ project_name }}.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = '{{ project_name }}.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/{{ docs_version }}/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/{{ docs_version }}/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

And still this errors are found in eclipse when I want to run in eclipse

Horizon --> Django--> Sync DB(manage.py syncdb)

```
WARNING:root:No local_settings file found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stack/git/horizon/manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = util.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 15, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
Finished "/home/stack/git/horizon/manage.py syncdb" execution.
```

Please help me to solve this error.

**Edited:**

Firstly I have DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE set problem.

I have set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to openstack_dashboard.settings.

and in horizon/openstack_dashboard folder I found settings.py and use database connection as answered below. Now it worked!!!

Comment: I found this:                                                      WARNING:root:No local_settings file found.
CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified `NAME` of the database.

### Edit

First of all you have to create a database with whatever database admin tool you are using. Then set it's name in your settings.py `NAME` variable.

Example:

If you create a new database called `mysiteDB`, then in your settings.py file, you need to do this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'mysiteDB',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Comment: Which database I should give. I have setup devstack and I can access through mysqlworkbench as a root. I tried giving nova but not worked.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have found two settings.py in this location  1. /home/Django/build/lib.linux-x86_64-

   2.7/django/conf/project_template/project_name

2. /home/Django/django/conf/project_template/project_name. I have changed in these file set ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] and replace your database connection string but still the same.

Comment: What do you mean two settings file?

Comment: I have got two settings.py file. Do I need to edit these two ?

Comment: One project and two settings files? Strange. Yeah edit both of them.